# How to download Docker images without a direct internet connection

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I see we can install tensorflow (with GPU) using Docker - here [TensorFlow - which Docker image to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34694701/tensorflow-which-docker-image-to-use)

But how do I do this on a machine that has no external internet connection?
Is there a way to first download the tensor flow image

```
b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu: TensorFlow GPU binary image
```

and then copy it to local file space and "install" it from there?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pull the image on a computer that have access to the internet.

```
sudo docker pull b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu
```

Then you can save this image to a file

```
sudo docker save -o tensorflow_image.docker b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu
```

Transfer the file on the offline computer (USB/CD/whatever) and load the image from the file:

```
sudo docker load < tensorflow_image.docker
```

Courtesy: https://serverfault.com/questions/701248/downloading-docker-image-for-transfer-to-non-internet-connected-machine

Comment: Does that mean I have to install docker on a second computer just to download the image?

Comment: You could use docker pull or maintain private registry. I get you. You don't want to install docker to get the image. You just want to pull up an image using wget/curl. This issue has been discussed here: https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1016

Comment: After doing the `docker load`, will the new local version of the transferred image have the original image name in the destination registry (in this case 'b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu')? I ask as the original image name isn't being specified during the load, and the Dockerfile I'm using refers to the image name used in the standard `docker pull <name:version>` call (don't want to change, to not introduce confusion).